# Audio dropouts over Bluetooth on Nexus One

Tags: nexus-one, bluetooth, 2.3-gingerbread, audio, a2dp

Ever since the Gingerbread update, my N1 has been experiencing random audio dropout problems every 5-10 minutes when connected to my car's audio system via Bluetooth. The audio will be streaming normally, then I'll hear a "pop" sound and the volume drops to zero, then immediately fades back in. The whole process lasts about three-quarters of a second, then everything is back to normal until the next dropout. This happens regardless of which audio application I am using. It does not happen when I am listening to the device over headphones or through the internal speaker. It did not happen under Froyo.

Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone have any idea about what might be causing it or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a typical Bluetooth interference problem. It happens to me from time to time, but I didn't notice any correlation with the Android version I use (neither on N1 nor NS).